# Разбить URL на значения и добавить класс чекбоксам у которых value-url совпадает с одним из параметров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть url типа /catalog/f/execution=фильтр%201,фильтр%202;switch-type=type1,type2,type3/

и чекбоксы типа

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="f[21][]" value="393" name="f[21][]" id="393" value-url="фильтр 1">
```

Нужно пройтись по url и поставить checked все чекбоксам в которых value-url совпадает с параметрами в урле.

Comment: У Вас не совпадает - пробел в `value-url="фильтр 1"`

Comment: Пробел убрал при создании вопроса. В реальном урле он существует

Comment: Хорошо, в каком из указанных действий Вы испытываете затруднения?

Comment: Я не знаю как правильно все это сделать. нужно ли быть урл на массив или же проверять урл как строку для каждого чекбокса. Не хочу писать криво а как это сделать хорошо мне не приходит в голову.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так осуществить

```
$(function() {
    var link = decodeURIComponent(location.href);
    var filter = {execution: link.replace(/.+execution\=([^;]+)\;?.*/, '$1').split(','), switchtype: link.replace(/.+switch\-type\=([^;]+)\;?.*/, '$1').split(',')};
    for(var i = 0; i < filter.execution.length; i++){
        $('input[value-url="'+filter.execution[i]+'"]').attr('checked', '');
    };
});
```

Comment: ДА но это сработает только на определенный параметр execution. А у меня они динамические в зависимости от выбраного фильтра

Comment: @АлександрГонтарь, не понял. Это сработает на все фильтры, которые вы укажите в url

Comment: execution, switch-type это названия фильтров в которых выбраны параметры. Но этих фильтром может быть много. Сейчас же ваш вариант работает только на execution.

Comment: @АлександрГонтарь, что вам мешает применить этот вариант на много фильтров?

Comment: фильтры создаются через админку сайта. Я не знаю как выбрать все возможные варианты фильтров

Comment: @АлександрГонтарь, я не знаю, что там у вас за фильтры. Вы задали вопрос - я ответил на него, а там уже подстраивайте

Comment: Спасибо вам.  Но просто я не пойму как мне принимать каждый параметр. это сейчас у меня execution и switch-type. но эти параметры постоянно меняются. тоесть возможно это будет  execution,switch-type,type,size,color.

Comment: @АлександрГонтарь, я немного изменил ответ. Нужно записывать каждый параметр или писать более сложноватый код, который будет создавать массив из всех параметров